# Blynk project on Arduino gets disconnected while initiating theater rainbow chase animation with NeoPixel

Tags: c++, arduino, neopixel

I am trying to create a simple project using Blynk on D1 Mini where I can select any animation any time and that should play unless I stop that using my Blynk App. While everything else working perfectly, I am not able to figure out what is wrong on my theaterchaserainbow function, that while selected, my D1 gets disconnected and connected again. Here is the code.

I understood from various forum that I must use blynk.timer instead and set count more than 1000L in setup. But that won't help me either for this particular theaterchaserainbow function. All other functions works perfectly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <BlynkSimpleEsp8266.h>
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#include <wifi_credentials.h>

#define BLYNK_PRINT Serial
#define myPixelPin D2
#define myPixels 16

char auth[] = "xxxxxxxmy_authxxxxxx";

int select;

BlynkTimer timer;

// Instatiate the NeoPixel from the ibrary
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(myPixels, myPixelPin, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

// Timer to repeat animations
void myTimerEvent() {
  if (select == 1) {
    allOff();
  } else if (select == 12) {
    theaterChaseRainbow(50);
  }
}

// NeoPixel all off Switch
BLYNK_WRITE(V0) {
  int pinValue = param.asInt();
  select = 1;
}

// Menu based Animation Selection
BLYNK_WRITE(V1) {
  int pinValue = param.asInt();
  switch (pinValue) {
    case 1: // Item 1
      select = 11;
      break;
    case 2: // Item 2
      select = 12;
      break;
  }
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Blynk.begin(auth, ssid, pass);
  strip.begin();
  strip.show();
  timer.setInterval(1000L, myTimerEvent);
}

void loop() {
  Blynk.run();
  timer.run(); // Initiates BlynkTimer;
}

// Theatre Chase Rainbow
//*****************************************************************************
void theaterChaseRainbow(uint8_t wait) {
  for (int j=0; j < 256; j++) {     // cycle all 256 colors in the wheel
    for (int q=0; q < 3; q++) {
        for (int i=0; i < strip.numPixels(); i=i+3) {
          strip.setPixelColor(i+q, Wheel( (i+j) % 255));    //turn every third pixel on
        }
        strip.show();
        delay(wait);
        for (int i=0; i < strip.numPixels(); i=i+3) {
          strip.setPixelColor(i+q, 0);        //turn every third pixel off
        }
    }
  }
}

//  Clear Program
//*****************************************************************************
void allOff() {
  for ( int i = 0; i < strip.numPixels(); i++ ) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, 0, 0, 0 );
  }
  strip.show();
}

// Default Wheel defination
//*****************************************************************************
uint32_t Wheel(byte WheelPos) {
  if (WheelPos < 85) {
    return strip.Color(WheelPos * 3, 255 - WheelPos * 3, 0);
  } else if (WheelPos < 170) {
    WheelPos -= 85;
    return strip.Color(255 - WheelPos * 3, 0, WheelPos * 3);
  } else {
    WheelPos -= 170;
    return strip.Color(0, WheelPos * 3, 255 - WheelPos * 3);
  }
}
```

Comment: while the animation is running Blynk.run() in loop is not executed, so Bynk stops responding

Comment: Blynk.run already inside void loop

Comment: 40 seconds is the sketch in theaterChaseRainbow. In this time Blynk.run is not executed to handle communication with Blynk server

Comment: So what do you think, a theaterChaseRainbow(100) should work?

Comment: it should be a function which would be called in every loop. inside the function the animation would be handled using timing with millis.

Comment: read the answer here https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/76396/implement-two-processes-at-the-same-time